# Highcharts :Cannot read property 'parentGroup' of undefined with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, highcharts

I'm doing a chart using the highChart and angularJS.
I follow this [highChart](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js/).

Here is my code:

- AngularJS:

  ```
  app.directive('hcPieChart', function () {

  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div></div>',
      scope: {
          title: '@',
          data: '='
      },
      link: function (scope, element) {
          Highcharts.chart(element[0], {
              chart: {
                  type: 'pie'
              },
              title: {
                  text: scope.title
              },
              plotOptions: {
                  pie: {
                      allowPointSelect: true,
                      cursor: 'pointer',
                      dataLabels: {
                          enabled: true,
                          format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.2f} %'
                      }
                  }
              },
              series: [{
                  data: scope.data
              }]
          });
      }
  };
  });

  app.controller('ChartsController', function ($scope) {
  var ids =location.search;
  $scope.Stats=function(){

             $http.get(url+"/Stats"+ids) 
              .success(function(data){
                  $scope.Stat = data;
              }).error(function(err,data){
                  console.log("error:" +data);
              }); 
          };      
          $scope.Stats();
  /*$scope.Stat = [{
                "Validate":17.456789,
                "NotValidate":2.96296,
                "Nb_V":2.96296,
                "Nb_Not_v":2.96296
            }];
   */
         // Sample data for pie chart
              $scope.pieData = [{
                      name: 'CheckLists Socred',
                      y:  $scope.Stat[0].Validate,
                      color: '#00c853'
                  },{
                      name: 'CheckLists Not Socred',
                      y: $scope.Stat[0].NotValidate,
                      color: '#b71c1c'
              }];
  });
  ```
- HTML code:

> ```
> <html >
> <head>
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
> </head>
> <body  ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChartsController" >
>      <hc-pie-chart title="Browser usage" data="pieData">Placeholder for pie chart</hc-pie-chart>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

What I got this chart
[image: My chart]

When from the graphic chart poster, I have this problem:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentGroup' of undefined
>       at k.setState (App/Template/highcharts/highcharts.js:392:112)
>       at App/Template/highcharts/highcharts.js:207:54
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at a.each (App/Template/highcharts/highcharts.js:27:360)
>       at a.Pointer.runPointActions (App/Template/highcharts/highcharts.js:207:32)
>       at k.onMouseOver (App/Template/highcharts/highcharts.js:389:130)
>       at SVGGElement.c (App/Template/highcharts/highcharts.js:380:323)

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z5cZS5od1FwaS1LYch33?p=preview)

thank you for helping me,

Comment: Could you reproduce it in jsfiddle example? (you could start from something like: http://jsfiddle.net/6vayegnk/)

Comment: I put on jsfiddle, but is not working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3exb68h/2/)

Comment: Let me know when you make it work. Or you can use other tool like plunker etc.

Comment: I think it's not the tool problem. But there is the problem in the code [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AlIq6VssoowU76BGUsz5?p=preview)

Comment: Your script.js is empty... Also you have problem with your html tags.

Comment: @stpoa I modify the link [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z5cZS5od1FwaS1LYch33?p=preview)

Comment: `script.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined at script.js:1`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and none of the answers helped me out. after several hours I figured out that the array which I was sending to the highchart component as the data feed to my chart, was causing the problem. 
the point is, that the y-axis records MUST be named as 'y' , not any other arbitrary name.

my data used to be like this:

```
data = [{name: "n1", income: 1491},
{name: "n2", income: 103103},
{name: "n3", income: 126886},
 {name: "n4", income: 88}]
```

and when i changed it to :

```
data = [{name: "n1", y: 1491},
{name: "n2", y: 103103},
{name: "n3", y: 126886},
 {name: "n4", y: 88}]
```

problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

According to `$scope.Stat` array object you have access each as `$scope.Stat[0].Validate`

[Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AIWbuWHdg7WRfbiUtaiu?p=preview)

```
$scope.pieData = [{
 name: 'CheckLists Socred',
                y:  $scope.Stat[0].Validate,
                color: '#00c853'
            },{
                name: 'CheckLists Not Socred',
                y: $scope.Stat[0].NotValidate,
                color: '#b71c1c'
        }];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @, I tried to do it but it returns this error message; `Can not read property 'resConforme' of undefined`

Comment: I can't find out in plunker above, could you elaborate the error

Comment: `$Scope.Stat ` its content is filled from another function in angularJS. How to make a global variable? I updated the post. @Deep

Comment: can you check using `console,log($scope.Stat)` just after `$scope.Stats()` and find error

Comment: It displays its `[object Object]`

Comment: use `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.Stat))`

Comment: It displays its `{}` ,Really i have not figured out why it is still empty @Deep

Comment: this is purely problem from server side `$http`, use appropriate debugging process in ueries