# How to display content $scope in HighCharts?

Tags: angularjs, html, highcharts

I'm doing a statistical graph using angularJs and highChartsJS.

Here is the code angularJS:

```
app.controller("StatController",function($scope,$http,fileUpload,$window, $filter)
 {
var ids=location.search; // id ressource

$scope.FindStats=function(){

                   $http.get(url+"/Stats"+ids) 
                    .success(function(data){
                        $scope.Stat = data;
                      console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.Stat));//{"idStat":21,"nbrBoks":7,"nbSection":5,"total":135,"resCon":0.0518519,"resNotCon":0.037037}
                    }).error(function(err,data){
                        console.log("error:" 
                       +data);
                    }); 
                };      

                $scope.FindStats();
 });
```

Html code:

```
<div>
 {{Stat}} 
<!--{"idStat":21,"nbrBoks":7,"nbSection":5,"total":135,"resCon":0.0518519,"resNotCon":0.037037} -->
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.2f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Result of books',
                y: '{Stat.resNotCon}', // error is here
                color: '#00c853',
            },{
                name: 'Result of section',
                y:'{Stat.resCon}', //error is here
                color: '#b71c1c',
            }]
        }]
    });
</script>
```

After a test of the code, I have a problem :

> Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14
>       at Object.a.error (http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:10:49)
>       at k.setData (http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:289:213)
>       at k.init (http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:282:174)
>       at a.Chart.initSeries (http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:248:70)
>       at http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:271:370
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at a.each (http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:27:360)
>       at a.Chart.firstRender (http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:271:341)
>       at a.Chart.init (http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:247:444)
>       at a.Chart.getArgs (http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:246:307)

So the problem is with the format of the data in highCharts.js:

> Highcharts Error #14
>
> String value sent to series.data, expected Number
>
> This happens if you pass in a string as a data point, for example in a
>   setup like this:
>
> series: [{    data: ["3", "5", "1", "6"] }] Highcharts expects the data
>   values to be numbers. The most common reason for this is that data is
>   parsed from CSV or from a XML source, and the implementer forgot to
>   run parseFloat on the parsed value.
>
> For performance reasons internal type casting is not performed, and
>   only the first value is checked (since 2.3).

**Edit1:**

```
data: [{
                name: 'Result of books',
                color: '#00c853',
                y: {Stat.resNotCon} // error is here
            },{
                name: 'Result of section',
                color: '#b71c1c',
                 y: {Stat.resCon} //error is here
            }]
```

**Error of edit1:**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token. in y: {Stat.resNotCon}

**Edit2:**

```
$scope.FindStats=function(){

                       $http.get(url+"/Stats"+ids) 
                        .success(function(data){
                            $scope.Stat = data;

 console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.Stat));//{"idStat":21,"nbrBoks":7,"nbSection":5,"total":135,"resCon":0.0518519,"resNotCon":0.037037}
                        }).error(function(err,data){
                            console.log("error:" 
                           +data);
                        }); 
                    };  
                $scope.FindStats();

                console.log("$scope "+$scope.Stat); //it's empty

                var Stat=$scope.Stat;

                console.log("after "+Stat); // it's empty
```

How to format data for highCharts.JS?

Thank you,

Comment: with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44454917/3898339) you are now getting proper data

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried as you said, but I have problem:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token. in `y: {Stat.resNotCon}` I updated the post

Comment: check this http://plnkr.co/edit/2NYCtm4tGTTEFt0ZIydL?p=preview  as answered earlier

Comment: this solution do not work for my, I have the graphic code in the `$scope.FindStats()` function, but the graph is not displayed on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to store the value of Stat in variable and not bind it to scope.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller("StatController",function($scope,$http,$window, $filter)
 {
    $scope.FindStats = function() {
     $scope.Stat = {
         "idStat": 21,
         "nbrBoks": 7,
         "nbSection": 5,
         "total": 135,
         "resCon": 0.0518519,
         "resNotCon": 0.037037
     };
 }
 $scope.FindStats();
 var Stat = $scope.Stat;


 Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.2f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Result of books',
                y: Stat.resNotCon, // error is here
                color: '#00c853',
            },{
                name: 'Result of section',
                y:Stat.resCon, //error is here
                color: '#b71c1c',
            }]
        }]
    });
 });
```

**Working Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11648/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this solution applies to static data. I want the applied on dynamic data returned from the function: `$scope.FindStats=function()`

Comment: You can call $scope.FindStats function on app load and assign the values to var Stat

Comment: How to call the `$scope.FindStats()` function on loading the application?

Comment: or you can add button and add `ng-click="$scope.FindStats()"`

Comment: I link to the statistical page. How to `<a href="..."> </a>` @Deep

Comment: I have `console.log ("after" + Stat);`  it's empty @Vivz

Comment: I am not getting  it as empty. $scope.FindStats();
var Stat=$scope.Stat;
console.log ("after" + Stat);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146322/discussion-between-vivz-and-michel).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Vivz , I put in a post the real solution

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved through the following code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller("StatController",function($scope,$http,$window, $filter,$RootScope)
 {
    $RootScope.FindStats = function() {
     $scope.Stat = {
         "idStat": 21,
         "nbrBoks": 7,
         "nbSection": 5,
         "total": 135,
         "resCon": 0.0518519,
         "resNotCon": 0.037037
     };

      Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.2f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Result of books',
                y: Stat.resNotCon, 
                color: '#00c853',
            },{
                name: 'Result of section',
                y:Stat.resCon, 
                color: '#b71c1c',
            }]
        }]
    });
 }
 $scope.FindStats();

 });
```